# Shopify: Where does block content added to in the theme Customize get stored?

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to retain content on pages with block content when exporting and importing a theme.

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried it? In the past when I've exported a theme, the customisation settings have come with it.

Comment: I'm moreso referring to the actual content in the custom blocks that I created within the theme sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the section/blocks/settings are kept in the `settings_data.json` file.

So when you transfer the theme they will be kept, but there are a few exceptions.

The following items will not be transferred if their selected items are not created:

- product field
- collection field
- navigation field
- blog field
- article field
- page field
- link_list field
- image_picker field

For all the fields ( except the image one ) if you create the targeted elements ( with the exact same handle ) you should be good to go.